# How to update Text file through internet? VB.Net

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer, vb.net-2010

I have AntiVirus , and I want to made an update button to update the text file which contain the virus list, it's call (viruslist.txt).
Every Time The user press Update button start check from my website if there's new virus list or no then update it by the new one...

Can u help me please in this case, actually I hear by Click once but I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
Dim update As String = Application.StartupPath & "/aaa.txt"
If File.Exists("aaa.txt") Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("aaa.txt")
    Me.Refresh()
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://test.com/aaa.txt", update)
ElseIf Not File.Exists("aaa.txt") Then
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://test.com/aaa.txt", update)
End If
```